# Create an SSL certificate for home network with XCA

Tags: ssl, webserver, certificate

I have a web server in my home network. Since it is a home network, there is no domain. I use the computer's name as the web site's address. For example, suppose the server's name is `vegetable`, then I type `https://vegetable` to open the web site.

I have been using XCA as a GUI tool to create SSL certificates. I had created an SSL certificate with it and put `vegetable` in the common name field and signed  it with a self-generated CA certificate that is shared among computers in my network. It worked well, but recently, Chrome started to refuse the certificate.

According to my quick Google search, it seems that I am supposed to use "SAN" instead of "common name", but a newly created certificate with `vegetable` in the SAN field did not work. Is this because I did something wrong, or because it does not fit the domain name format (something like `app.google.com`)? As I have written, it is a home network, so I do not have a domain name.

In this case, is it possible for me to create a proper certificate with XCA? If so, how? The examples I have found using Google search all seemed to use the "common name".

Answer (score 0):

You should fill "SAN" and "common name" with **vegatable**. In SAN you can add more aliases if needed.